# Where can I find an installation / configuration guide for amateur radio features, on Ubuntu?

Tags: internet-radio, ham-radio

I'm a Ubuntu user from way back to the point where I supported it for a professional software team. I am, myself, a Java Developer. Recently I got my Amateur Radio license. Where can I find guidance on how to set up my System76 laptop such that it has packages and configurations such as those available on Skywave Linux, which is a Ham derivation of Ubuntu?

https://skywavelinux.com/

[Edit]

I've found a bread crumb.

https://hamwaves.com/linux.ham.packages/en/index.html

Comment: The question is too broad. How do we know what "packages and configurations" that distro has?

Comment: I'll rephrase. I'm not asking for the kitchen sink.